# Relying on table comments with MySQL

Tags: mysql, metatable

I'm building an application that adds/removes/alters tables in a MySQL database. Some tables have specific application roles and need to be tagged and identified as such by the application. Can I depend on table comments to reliably store this meta information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built code that uses table and column comments to hold meta information as you mention. It works very well.

My application was tagging particular tables and columns in a medical information system as needing to be  concealed when exporting the data, to preserve patient confidentiality.

You do need to ensure that the comments get dumped along with other schema information when you save your schema (for example, to store the schema in your source control system).

I used capitalized keywords in the comments, to make it possible to also include real explanatory comments side by side with the metadata.

Go for it!

Comment: cool, I just wanted to be sure that there wasn't a reason why comments might be unexpectedly purged or overwritten. Thanks!